# Entering the Philippines with no booking of flight and ferries to travel within Philippines

Tags: indian-citizens, philippines, visas-on-arrival

I am traveling to the Philippines on my Singapore visa (Indian passport). I will be traveling to Singapore then the Philippines. I have booked my hotel in Quezon City for my 12-day stay, and itinerary is limited to Luzon.

Can there be any issue? Any chances of getting deported (I heard that a lot of people get deported for multiple reasons) because I don't have flight and ferry bookings to travel around in the Philippines?

Comment: Do you have a flight booked to leave the Philippines (and have the correct paperwork to be eligible to enter that destination)?

Comment: @Traveller Yes, I have flight booked for exit, and correct paperwork to enter

Answer (score 5):

There's no obligation to tour around the Phils. You can definitely stay within one city and enjoy the sights there. As long as you have a flight that leaves, and a hotel booking, and you satisfy immigration rules (in your case, having a Singapore visa in lieu of a Philippines visa), you'll be fine.